# Concatenate non-image feature vector (dimension 3x1) with the image feature vector (dimension Nx1) at the flattend layer of CNN & fed to dense layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with a chest X-ray image dataset containing 15 classes. Image filenames are reserved in a CSV file with some non-image values. The image dataset is split into train, test, validation. I used imagedatagenerator to augment images.

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      Image Index    |  Patient Gender  | View Position |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|   00008236_001.png  |         1        |       0       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|   00016410_014.png  |         0        |       1       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|   00014751_001.png  |         1        |       0       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|   00020318_012.png  |         1        |       1       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

[[CSV file  containing non image features (Patient gender and chest x-ray image view position are encoded as {0,1})]

I want to concatenate these two column's values with the flattened layer of CNN.

I tried the following code but it showed error.

```
train_set_features = train_set[['View Position','Patient Gender']]
input_features =train_set_att.values # Shape=(90771, 2)

from keras.applications import *
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten,Concatenate
from keras.models import Sequential

base_model = MobileNet( include_top=False,input_shape=(224,224,3))
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)  #output shape = (None,7168)
non_image_features = Input(shape=[2,], name="non_image") #output shape = (None,2)
x= concatenate([x, non_image_features]) #output shape = (None,7170)

# and a logistic layer
predictions = Dense(15, activation="sigmoid",name='visualized_layer')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[base_model.input,non_image_features], outputs=predictions)
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['binary_accuracy','mae'])
history = model.fit_generator([train_generator,input_features ],
                              validation_data=valid_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=100, 
                              validation_steps=25,
                              epochs =64,)

predicted_values = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps = len(test_generator))
```

Is this the right way to concatenate values with flattened layer?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with your code. First, you try to call `concatenate`, but there is no such function. Notice that the function you import is named `Concatenate`.

Second, if you try to call this function then you need to do it in a different way. Check the documentation to see how it works (look for examples of use): https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/

Lastly, if you will still experience problems, please report us the error you are receiving so we can try to find out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I checked keras documentation for Cancatenation. Then, I changed my code. 
`non_image_features = Input(shape=[2,], name="non_image") `
`x= Concatenate(axis=1)([x, non_image_features]) `
`predictions = Dense(15, activation="sigmoid",name='visualized_layer')(x)`

After editing, the model is compiled successfully. But model.fit_generator shows this error. 
`TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator`
Code:
`history = model.fit_generator([train_generator,input_features ],
                              validation_data=valid_generator,epochs =64,)`

Comment: I am confused about `([train_generator,input_features ],`. How can i correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as already pointed out, it's `Concatenate`, not `concatenate`.

From the documentation, fit_generator expects a generator, not a list `[train_generator,input_features ]`. The generator is expected to yield a tuple - `(inputs, targets)` at every iteration. Each batch (generated at each iteration ) usually contain about 64 or 128 training examples.

In your case the first argument is most likely `train_generator` and not `[train_generator,input_features ]`